# Умные указатели и утечка памяти

Tags: c++, утечка-памяти, smart-pointer

Изучаю умные указатели и абстрактные базовые классы.

Есть следующий интерфейс:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <memory>

#define PURE_VIRTUAL =0

namespace linalg {
    class _btensor;
    class vector;

    using _btensor_uptr = std::unique_ptr<_btensor>;

    class _btensor 
    {
    public:
        virtual _btensor_uptr identity_(double(*custom_norm)(const _btensor&) = nullptr) const PURE_VIRTUAL;
    };

    using dyn_array = std::vector<double>;
    using init_list = std::initializer_list<double>;
    class vector : public _btensor
    {
    public:
        dyn_array data_;
    public:
        explicit vector(const dyn_array&);
        vector(const init_list&);

        _btensor_uptr identity_(double(*custom_norm)(const _btensor&) = nullptr) const override;
    };
}
```

И реализация:

```
#include "linalg.hpp"

using namespace linalg;

vector::vector(const dyn_array& data)
    : data_(data)
{
}

vector::vector(const init_list& il)
    : data_(il)
{
}

_btensor_uptr vector::identity_(double(*custom_norm)(const _btensor &)) const
{
    using std::make_unique;

    double norm_val = (custom_norm == nullptr ? norm() : custom_norm(*this));

    dyn_array new_data(data_.size());
    for (dyn_array::size_type i = 0; i < data_.size(); ++i) new_data[i] = data_[i] / norm_val;

    return static_cast<_btensor_uptr>(make_unique<vector>(new_data));
}
```

Вызываю так:

```
#include <vld.h>

#include "linalg.hpp"

int main()
{
    using linalg::vector;

    vector v = { 1.11, 2.12, 3.99 };

    v.identity_();
    return 0;
}
```

Программа отрабатывает корректно, но кроме всего прочего, в отладке использую Visual Leak Detector 2.5.1, который говорит, что при вызове `v.identity_()` возникает утечка памяти:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
---------- Block 6 at 0x0000000000384F80: 16 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0x9A3E07BD, Count: 1, Total 16 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 7804):
    ucrtbased.dll!malloc()
    linalg.exe!0x000000013F3C9833()
    ...
    linalg.exe!0x000000013F3CA369()
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0xD bytes
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x1D bytes
  Data:
    E8 7A 39 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00    00 00 00 00     .z9..... ........

---------- Block 7 at 0x000000000038A430: 24 bytes ----------
  Leak Hash: 0xEB8C4A1B, Count: 1, Total 24 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 7804):
    ucrtbased.dll!malloc()
    linalg.exe!0x000000013F3C9833()
    ...
    linalg.exe!0x000000013F3CA369()
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0xD bytes
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x1D bytes
  Data:
    F9 12 AE E6    AE 89 CE 3F    DB 44 6A 0A    89 29 DD 3F     .......? .Dj..).?
    36 83 15 B7    59 71 EB 3F                                   6...Yq.? ........


Visual Leak Detector detected 2 memory leaks (144 bytes).
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: У вас отсутствует `custom delleter`,  по этому 2 утечки памяти, первый элемент вектора удаляется, потому что вызывается `delete`, а дальше нет, нужен `delete[]`. У вас вектор, это массив, а для массивов нужен `custom delleter`.

Comment: @B1aZe, Я не уверен. Вектор в себе агрегирует массив, но сам им не является. На сколько я понимаю, unique_ptr должен вызвать в нужный момент деструктор для linalg::vector а тот, в свою очередь вызовет деструктор для data_, который std::vector<double> aka linalg::dyn_array. В конце концов я явно нигде не вызываю ни new ни new[], а значит, по моей логике, std::vector<double> должен сам позаботиться об очистке памяти. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: А если `vector v = { 1.11, 2.12, 3.99 };  v.identity_();` взять в фигурные скобки? `... { vector v = { 1.11, 2.12, 3.99 }; v.identity_(); } return 0;`

Comment: @B1aZe, Что? Ну, вообще-то я просто пробегаюсь по нему и задаю значения. К тому же это std::vector<double>, он безопасно очистится по выходу из области видимости. А создается он тут - `dyn_array new_data(data_.size());` это равносильно `std::vector<double> new_data(data_.size());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что происходит в строке `static_cast<_btensor_uptr>(make_unique<vector>(new_data));` при преобразовании `unique_ptr<vector>` в  `unique_ptr<_btensor_uptr>`?
Право владения передается от указателя одного типа к указателю другого типа. Хотя физически он указывает на тот же самый адрес в памяти, информация о типе по этому адресу данных - теряется. unique_ptr в своем деструкторе, вызвал бы деструктор для vector, а новый умный указатель вызовет деструктор только для _btensor . Поскольку деструктор _btensor невиртуальный, то будут вызваны деструкторы только для членов данны *btensor (их нет). Т.е. data* (из vector) останется неочищенным.

Решений два: либо добавить виртуальный деструктор в _btensor , либо перейти к использованию shared_ptr вместо unique_ptr (они, при касте указателей, сохраняют функцию-делетор см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast ).

Прямой вызов static_cast для умных указателей, как и для любых классов, вообще очень плохая практика. Не делайте так.